# Multiple Provisioning profiles for iOS azure build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am unable to build our app which having multiple provisioning profiles like IntentExtension and IntentExtensionUI .

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no support of multiple provisioning profiles for Xcode task (for example for iOS App Extension). You could check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops#using-multiple-provisioning-profiles

As a work around, you need an "exportOptions.plist". This allows you to include multiple schemes and their associated provisioning profiles (eg. if you have a Today Widget or Intents as well as your main project).

Refer to this for details: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8811